# Substitute for coating ramekin in a chocolate soufflé.

Tags: chocolate, souffle

I know that when it comes to chocolate soufflés, the substance to coat a ramekin to help the soufflé climb is sugar.

Here's my question: can I use something else, like salt? Or cocoa powder?

I only ask because sugar can be a little too sweet for me, and I know that salt and chocolate can sometimes work together like in chocolate coated pretzels.

Any thoughts?

Comment: I wouldn't do *just* salt (I think that would be too salty), or *just* cocoa (I don't think that would give the souffle enough to grab on to. However, a well-mixed mixture of all three ingredients (including sugar) could be brilliant.

Comment: I actually think cocoa powder would work just fine, as would flour...and salt. Why not make a batch with various ramekin coatings?  Could be an interesting experiment to learn if there is an actual physical difference, and to determine with flavor you prefer.

Comment: On a budget and can't afford to experiment.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can coat the buttered edges of the ramekin in anything you like that will withstand the heat during the cooking process.  Chopped Nuts, cocoa, flour, whatever you wish to go with your chocolate souffle.

Comment: Chopped nuts is a great idea.  There's a place near me that sells pecan meal (finely ground pecans) that's a similar size to sugar grains, too.